# SSSD LDAP authentication using two different LDAP servers

Tags: centos, openldap, login, pam, sssd

I am trying to setup LDAP authentication using SSSD on CentOS 7.

Is it possible to set up SSSD in a way that it uses two LDAP servers: one LDAP server is used just for authentification (basically just to authenticate with the password) and other LDAP server is used for identification and getting all the attributes of a user (homeDirectory, additional LDAP attributes defined only on that LDAP server)?

Users are defined on both servers (same uid, but different base)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the long run you'd be better off finding a way to merge your bases.
However, [`SASL Pass-Through Authentication`](http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/security.html#Pass-Through%20authentication) may be an option for you. Unless you're already using it to pass your main authentication over to something like Kerberos, in which case, you'd be best served replicating the `userPassword` entry as it's likely to remain static, it should allow you to use the other base to authentication.

Answer (score 3):

No, I don't think this is possible except with an ugly hack. The only special-case that sssd supports is a different LDAP server for change password operations (with `ldap_chpass_uri`).

But what you could do is to use `id_provider=proxy`, configure it to use nslcd (aka nss-pam-ldapd) and configure nslcd to use the identity LDAP server. Then configure `auth_provider=ldap` and point it to the auth LDAP server.

It's not pretty and you would have two LDAP daemons running, but I can't think of another way of solving the problem.